# Slicing arrays with meshgrid/array indices in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code:

```
    big_k = gabor((height * 2, width *2), (height, width)) #Returns a 2d-array
    r = np.arange(0, radialSlices, radialWidth)
    p = np.arange(0, angularSlices, angularWidth)
    pp, rr = np.meshgrid(p, r, sparse=False)
    z = np.sum(img * big_k[height-rr:2*height-rr, width-pp:2*width-pp])
```

I get this error:

```
    z = np.sum(img * big_k[height-rr:2*height-rr, width-pp:2*width-pp])
IndexError: invalid slice
```

I understand this error and why it has happened. The problem is you can't slice arrays with arrays of indices. The thing is, using meshgrid is a fabulous way to speed things up & get rid of the nested loops in my code (otherwise I would have to iterate over `angularSlices * radialSlices`). Is there a way I can use `meshgrid` to slice `big_k`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to broadcast the index yourself, for example:

```
a = np.zeros((200, 300))

yy, xx = np.meshgrid([10, 40, 90], [30, 60])
hh, ww = np.meshgrid(np.arange(5), np.arange(8))

YY = yy[..., None, None] + hh[None, None, ...]
XX = xx[..., None, None] + ww[None, None, ...]

a[YY, XX] = 1
```

the image looks like:

[image]

Comment: Very clever. OK I will try and implement it and report back! Thansk!

Comment: I've tried to do this and I'm a bit stuck. I can reproduce what you've done, but I can't figure out how to operate (np.sum) on the final window (as opposed to just set it to '1').

Effectively what my code should do is generate a filter 'big_k', twice the size of the image, which is then cropped & translated at regular points across the image, and then the total value of the pixels at each point is saved to a 2d array.